# dynamic dns not being picked up

Tags: nginx, dns, network-programming, dyndns

I am trying to link a page running on my local machine to my reserved domain name, but it does not seem to get picked up.

I have installed nginx on an ubuntu 18.04 machine. I have a simple hello world tutorial folder with the following conf settings:

```
server {
       listen 81;
       listen [::]:81;

       server_name api.<my_domain>.net;

       root /var/www/tutorial;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

I enabled dynamic dns with my hosting provider. Then I generated the following settings with ddclient, entering the data as given by my hosting provider under step 2 here: https://www.strato-hosting.co.uk/faq/webshop/this-is-how-easy-it-is-to-set-up-dyndns-for-your-domains/

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

protocol=dyndns2
use=web
server=https://dyndns.strato.com/nic/update
login=<my_username>
password='<my_dyndns_password>'
api.<my_domain>.net
```

I also edited the dhcp client to true:

```
# Configuration for ddclient scripts 
# generated from debconf on zo  9 jan 2022 21:20:14 CET
#
# /etc/default/ddclient

# Set to "true" if ddclient should be run every time DHCP client ('dhclient'
# from package isc-dhcp-client) updates the systems IP address.
run_dhclient="true"

# Set to "true" if ddclient should be run every time a new ppp connection is 
# established. This might be useful, if you are using dial-on-demand.
run_ipup="false"

# Set to "true" if ddclient should run in daemon mode
# If this is changed to true, run_ipup and run_dhclient must be set to false.
run_daemon="true"

# Set the time interval between the updates of the dynamic DNS name in seconds.
# This option only takes effect if the ddclient runs in daemon mode.
daemon_interval="300"
```

If I try the following from another laptop I get these results:

- `<internal_device_ip>:81` works from a laptop on the same network
- `<external_ip_address>:81` works from a laptop on an external network
- `api.<my_domain>.net:81` fails

I feel like I am missing some simple configuration setting to connect the last dot.

Comment: did you check that api.<my_domain>.net gets resolved into UP-TO-DATE <external_ip_address> ? It takes time for DNS changes to propagate so probably you did not wait long enough for domain name to point to new IP address.

Comment: Your hint definitely helped me search in the right direction. I never added 'api' as an actual subdomain with my hosting provider, so it was trying to match it to the main domain. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It threw the error because I had not added `api.<my_domain>.net` as a subdomain with my hosting provider. Once I did, I could access `api.<my_domain>.net:81` from an external browser.